# Salesforce API reset password not working for certain accounts

Tags: rest-api, force.com, php, partner-portal

I have a Salesforce support cases self-service partner portal built using the Force.com PHP Toolkit. Everything is working fine with the portal except for certain users cannot use the "Forgot Password" feature. It sends them an activation email to reset their password, they set their new password, and then they cannot log in with the new password. The only way to resolve the issue for these users is to completely delete them from Salesforce and then re-add them as a new account. Then they can login to the system successfully and use the "Forgot Password" feature as much as they want without any issues.

I cannot determine any difference between an affected account and all other users that have no issues. Deleting the user from Salesforce is not a good long term solution because we lose all of their previous support cases.

Has anyone else ran into an issue like this and found a better solution then completely removing the user?

Comment: Sounds unusual, I would recommend raising a support case